# ClientLogin for Picasa Web Albums Data API with a Google App Domain login

Tags: c#, picasa, google-data

I'm using the Picasa Web Albums Data API to access users' photo albums from a WPF application.

I've followed the code located here:
http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/clientlogin.html

I have created a Picasa Web Albums account with a Google Apps (hosted) account.  Whenever I tried logging in with my WPF application, I get the "BadAuthentication" error code returned.

Hoping someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong.  Note, that this works when I login with a normal Google account.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
GDataGAuthRequestFactory authFactory = new GDataGAuthRequestFactory("lh2", _appName);
authFactory.AccountType = "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE";

_picasaService = new PicasaService(authFactory.ApplicationName);
_picasaService.RequestFactory = authFactory;

_picasaService.setUserCredentials(username, password);
return _picasaService.QueryAuthenticationToken();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around a bit, I changed the `AccountType = "GOOGLE"`, and that worked.

Thinking about it, that makes sense.  I created the account using an existing email address.  So in this situation, I was logging into the Google account, not the hosted account.

Originally, I had not specified a `RequestFactory`, so the code looked like this:

```
_picasaService = new PicasaService(_appName);

_picasaService.setUserCredentials(username, password);
return _picasaService.QueryAuthenticationToken();
```

This would cause a "Invalid User" error.  I originally thought that I would need to set the `AccountType = "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE"`, to get this to work.  I had that in my head.  So I added the `RequestFactory`, thinking that would solve my problems.

Looking at the documentation for [GDataGAuthRequestFactory](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn/docs/folder16/AllMembers_T_Google_GData_Client_GDataGAuthRequestFactory.htm).  It states that the `AccountType` is defaulted to `"GOOGLE_OR_HOSTED"`, so I tried this code:

```
GDataGAuthRequestFactory authFactory = new GDataGAuthRequestFactory("lh2", _appName);
authFactory.AccountType = "GOOGLE_OR_HOSTED";

_picasaService = new PicasaService(authFactory.ApplicationName);
_picasaService.RequestFactory = authFactory;
```

And that works.  I have to conclude that the documented default value for `AccountType` of `"GOOGLE_OR_HOSTED"` is not correct.

Comment: I've submitted an issue report to the owners for the Google Data Api for .net:  
http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/issues/detail?id=247

Answer (score 0):

`HOSTED` means a Google Apps account, `GOOGLE`  means a Google Account.
You have to decide on your own, this isn't exactly a bug in documentation..